# Disabling touch interaction of Spaces between Custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, cellspacing

I use custom cells of subclassing UITableViewCell in a table view. And There must be space between cells. I succesfully add the space with adding a subview that I called SpaceView into the content view. But When I touched the spaceView, it is perceived as I touched the cell. And didSelectRow method called. I tried to set spaceView's `UserInteractionEnabled==NO`. But It doesn't work.

**So my question is; Is this the right way I used to add space between cells ? Should I try to add cells for making the space ? or If its the right way, How can I prevent calling "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method when I touched spaceView ?**

Comment: I think you are looking for `[tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

like Inder said below, u can use an UIButton to solve the issue.

1) in your custom cell: at the bottom of your custom cell add a blank UIButton with the height u actually need between cells, and customize its background color according to your needs.

2) in cellforrowatindexpath: disable button of each cell. (or you can also do that in Interface Builder of previous step)

result: u have a clear **disabled** button that will appear as required space between cells.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `spaceView` as `UIButton` (I guess it's `UIView` right now)

When you add `UIButton` that touch will be consumed by the button thus touch won't be passed to it's parent.

**OR**

I'm not sure if it will work or not, you can add tap gesture to your `spaceView`

Comment: It doesn't work because didselectRowAtIndexPath delegate called when cell's content view touched, When I add Button, it becomes subview of cell's content view.

Comment: Mustafa it was working in my sample. You can download that [sample from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/exg521g76cbgac3/ObjcTest.zip?dl=0)